# Hooks in the name of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Unfortunately I have to take an Excel file that contains a column name => endOfWork [4]

I then want to export it using a SQL query. I rename my columns and can not put brackets as requested:

```
TMP_TBL_Sedex_modif.Champ98 AS startOfWork [23]
```

How to put square brackets in my SQL query?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQl Server <> MySQL. What are you *really* using?

Comment: i use Sql Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Square brackets are used in SQL Server as characters to delimit [Delimited Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017), which are allowed to contain characters not allowed in Regular Identifiers (and are also allowed to be SQL keywords).

If you wish to use square brackets within the name, you have to escape one of them:

```
select 1 as [startOfWork [23]]]
```

Alternatively, assuming the default settings, you can use double-quotes as the delimiter instead:

```
select 1 as "startOfWork [23]"
```

Comment: Or (since this is an alias and not an identifier) simply `select 1 as 'startOfWork [23]'` which should work just fine regardless of server settings...

Comment: @ZoharPeled - square brackets work fine regardless of settings. I'm not a fan of the single quotes form. It's "inappropriate" mixing. Aliases belong in the same "namespace" as other identifiers, you (IMO) shouldn't be putting string literals in when you want one.

Comment: Yes, square brackets will work under any settings, though it looks quite cumbersome to use in this case, so personally I don't really like this solution. I don't think using a string literal as an alias is necessarily a bad thing but I do get your point.